How can I get around 16 electrical receptacles in a small area with the least amount of wiring?
I need around 8-16 receptacles for many low powered devices on a server rack. They will share a circuit because they are low power. I want to basically hard wire a power strip, but avoid the safety issues of power strips.
I could buy 2x(8 units) of receptacles, but then I would be connecting 8 units to each other for the wiring. I could buy something like the Leviton 05480-305-0GY, which offers 2x2 receptacles in one unit, wired similarly to a 2x1:

Then I would only need 4x(4 units).
Are there any UL-listed receptacles that offer more than 4 receptacles per wiring job? Is there another way to do this?

There might be, but most people do not need them so they might be more expensive than four by fours.  There are receptacle extenders(make six out of a double, but then you have an extra connection(plug in extension, plug in plug) not really needed/can get loose.

this might help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=server+rack+power+bar&iax=images&ia=images

Power strips are not a safety issue per se. They have their power rating and their voltage drop considerations. They will not get safer just because they get embedded in the wall. On the other hand, you need your power estimate first anyway.

You can get hardwired power strips.  https://www.x1up.com/product-category/hardwired-power-strips/  You are coy about your packaging requirements, so no idea if this form factor meets your use case.

The standard method for providing power to equipment racks is a vertical multiple outlet strip mounted to the rack rails inside the cabinet on one side (with signal wires on the opposite side to avoid EFI).
An alternative scheme uses rack-width horizontal power strips.
If you select branded and UL approved strips listed for rack installation, they will likely be safer than anything you cobble together.
(I worked as an industry certified audiovisual designer and installer for over 30 years.)

Both of those links (16 hours after posting) are 404ing. However the important point is that these are IEC receptacles, which might or might not be preferable in the application.

@MarkMorganLloyd links work for me.

@MarkMorganLloyd They have them with BS 1363 style connectors too, so I'd assume a NEMA variant would be available too (maybe a different supplier). The point is sound -- a quality power bar is better than something hand-cobbled. The "safety issues" OP links to seem more about the cheap and crappy extension cords from dollar stores/etc.

@Huesmann They've been broken for me too. Maybe the site does something funny based on location?

The links work if you change the region in the top-right to US or Canada but any other region gives a 404 error.

Recommendation for the flaky links: post a picture of the object from the linked website, then use the link as a source. The picture will help those who cannot see the linked website know what you're suggesting, and the source link will suit for the requirements of SE for attribution of posting someone else's picture.

Downvoting because rack-mounted equipment is rarely connected to a power strip.  This answer contradicts the question by recommending the exact thing asked about avoiding, and lacks any reference supporting the idea that hard wired receptacles are less safe.  It is anecdotal and ignores other options and the likely need to interface with power conditioning solutions.  Without knowing about those options being hardwired, or whether hard wired receptacles could be attached to a cord and plug tap, I feel like the answer is not adequate.

@Robert Chapin - OP stated his question as, "I want to basically hard wire a power strip, but avoid the safety issues of power strips."  The solution proposed is a safe and tidy power strip.   He did not include power conditioning, current monitoring, sequential start-up, or other features of, say, PDU's.  I don't follow your hardwire argument; rack equipment is almost never hardwired (the most likely exception being rack-mounted outlet strips).  His power source was a Nema socket, and his load devices required Nema sockets distributed throughout the rack.
